# mxGraph add component

Tags: java, mxgraph

I'm trying to create a scrollable and tabbed palette, but it fail.
There is a code particle (necessary implementations are done)

```
        // Creates the shapes palette
    EditorPalette shapesPalette = insertPalette(mxResources.get("shapes"));
    EditorPalette imagesPalette = insertPalette(mxResources.get("images"));
    EditorPalette symbolsPalette = insertPalette(mxResources.get("symbols"));
```

**InsertPalette :**

```
public EditorPalette insertPalette(String title)
{
    final EditorPalette palette = new EditorPalette();
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(palette);
    scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane
            .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    libraryPane.add(title, scrollPane);

    // Updates the widths of the palettes if the container size changes
    libraryPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            int w = scrollPane.getWidth()
                    - scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getWidth();
            palette.setPreferredWidth(w);
        }

    });

    return palette;
}
```

When I run this code, created a palette, but it is not tabbed.
how can I solve this problem.

thnx :)

Comment: ** I am adding some template cell each palette, but create just one **

Comment: ''shapesPalette.addTemplate("Icon",
    new ImageIcon(GraphEditor.class.getResource("/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/images/rounded.png")),
    "icon;image=/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/images/wrench.png", 70, 70, "Icon");imagesPalette.addTemplate("Wrench",
    new ImageIcon(GraphEditor.class.getResource("/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/images/wrench.png")),
    "roundImage;image=/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/images/wrench.png", 50, 50, "Wrench");' '